# Bootstrap doesn't load with Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

My web have Struts 2 and Bootstrap. When i try to go a other page with Struts' tags, Bootstrap doesn't load.

This is the tag that i use in the index.jsp for go to the next page

```
<s:a action="MostrarInmuebles">Mostrar</s:a>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="MostrarInmuebles" class="es.actions.MostrarInmuebles" method="Mostrar">
    <result name="success">pages/muebles.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

MostrarInmuebles.java

```
public class MostrarInmuebles extends ActionSupport {

private ArrayList<Piso> pisos = new ArrayList<Piso>();

private PisoDAO pisodao = new PisoImpl();


public String Mostrar() {

    System.out.println("Entro en mostrar pisos");
    pisos = pisodao.MostrarPisos();
    return SUCCESS;

}
public ArrayList<Piso> getPisos() {
    return pisos;
}
```

Muebles.jsp, for now it only show this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags"  prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Báltico | Contacto </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../images/inmobiliaria.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

   <!-- logo -->
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.jsp"><img alt="INMOBILIARIA" src="../images/inmocap.png"></a>   
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse animated fadeIn" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav animated fadeIn text16">
       <li>
          <a href="#" ><b><strong>Índice</b></strong></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Quienes somos</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>&nbsp;Servicios</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;Inmuebles</a>

        </li>
          <li>
        <a href="#"">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>&nbsp;Preguntas Frecuentes</a>
      </li>

        <li>
        <a href="#">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>&nbsp;Contacto y localización</a>
      </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>                      

</nav>
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 style="color:red">Inmobilaria </h1>
            <p><i>"ASESORAMIENTO FINANCIERO GRATUITO"<br>
              "PRETASACIÓN DE SU VIVIENDA GRATUITA" </i></p>
        </div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just replace `../css` with some relative, absolute or dynamic url. like `/css`, `https://www.example.com/css`, or a path calculated with s:property

Comment: Andrea Ligios, Many thanks! I used <s:url> in my links and the page shows.

Comment: Good! Feel free to answer yourself and accept your own answer, to help future visitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed my problem changing this lines in Muebles.jsp:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6
/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<s:url value="/css/estilos.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```